# Programatically Show/Hide the FROM field in Outlook using c#

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-2007, outlook-2010

Is there any way to show/hide the FROM field in Outlook programatically?

The reason I want to do this, is because some code i've wrote so far successfully sets the FROM field.

However, after the first time it is ran, the FROM field is set, but the UI doesn't reflect this change.

Hiding and then re-showing the FROM field forces the UI to update. Ideally I want to find a way to do this in both 2007 and 2010.

If it isn't possible to hide and re-show the FROM field programatically is there any other way to force the UI to refresh?

```cs
//Get the explorer window and the currently selected item
Explorer activeExplorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();
MailItem origMsg = activeExplorer.Selection[1];

Recipients origRecipients = origMsg.Recipients;

if (origRecipients.Count == 1)
{
    AddressEntry address = origRecipients[1].AddressEntry;
    currentMsg.Sender = address;

    //currentMsg.SentOnBehalfOfName = origRecipients[1].Name; currentMsg.send
}
```